# Cannot bind port 8531 to https through IIS 8 for WSUS

Tags: wsus, iis-8

Our WSUS previously had https bound to port 8531 in IIS, but I was trying to get SSL to work on it and ran into some issues where my WSUS console wouldn't connect anymore. The event logs were showing some errors about not being able to reach 0.0.0.0:8531.

I wasn't sure how to undo the wsusutil.exe configuressl  command so that my wsus server wouldn't use SSL anymore so I attempted to just delete the SSL certs from IIS and removed the binding.

After I did all that and tried to re-add the same port binding for https, the OK button is now greyed out and I can't re-add it. Anyone know how to fix this? At this point, I'm thinking it might be easier to just scrap everything and start from scratch as this was originally set up by someone else and I am just trying to go over all the configurations and make adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it looks like I have to create a SSL cert before I can bind a HTTPS port. When I originally checked the configurations there wasn't an existing cert but the https protocol was somehow bound to port 8531 so I was confused.